# Limiting sensor reading into 4 decimal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am a newbie to Python. I am fetching sensor readings and it has too many decimal places (`x.xxxxxxxx`)
I want to limit the reading into 4 decimals places (`x.xxxx`).

```
from altimu10v5.lsm6ds33 import LSM6DS33
from altimu10v5.lis3mdl import LIS3MDL
from altimu10v5.lps25h import LPS25H

from time import sleep

lsm6ds33 = LSM6DS33()
lsm6ds33.enable()

lps25h = LPS25H()
lps25h.enable()

lis3mdl = LIS3MDL()
lis3mdl.enable()

while True:

    #print(lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_raw())
    print("{:.2f}".format.lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces())

    sleep(0.4)
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

`" attribute error : ' builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'lsm6ds33'`

Comment: Is `print("...".format.something)` the right syntax in Python?

Comment: @Trilarion, it's close. `print("...".format(something))` would be closer. The ancient `%`-based syntax is still around, but not preferred; an even more modern replacement would be to use a f-string.

Comment: @saran, btw, we generally prefer that questions be made to the shortest possible thing that lets someone else observe the same problem. If `g_force=0.123456789` and then `print("{:.2f}".format.g_force)` shows the same problem, then you could make your question just two lines and not specific to Raspberry Pi's at all, to be providing a [mre] that anyone could test.

Comment: okey , understood ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
print("{:.4f}".format(lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()))
```

- Reference: [Python: str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

**EDIT**: In cases where you have an array of values that you wish to string.format(), iterate over each value using a for loop and format them one at a time. Like so:

```
# Assuming "lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()" returns the array [-0.5555, -0.78788, 0.878888]...

accelArray= lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces() #temp variable to hold the array

for accelNumber in accelArray:
    print("{:.4f}".format(accelNumber))
```

Given the array [-0.5555, -0.78788, 0.878888], the above loop will output:

```
-0.5555
-0.7879
0.8789
```

Comment: hei
im having a new error :
ValueError : Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

any idea.

Comment: Are you sure that the value you get from `get_accelerometer_g_forces()` is a float? If not, you may need to convert it to a float before using `str.format()` on it.

Another possible reasong, could be that perhaps this only works in Python3. Are you using Python2? Do you know your Python version (`python -V`)?

Comment: you are right.
its python2.
i have both python 3 and python2 in my pi.
for some reason im unable to install library of the sensor for python3 ( but able to install on python 2).
get_accelerometer_g_forces() is a float , 
so any ways to make it in python2 .

Comment: I just tried the same solution on a Python 2.7 interpreter, and it still worked. So, I suspect the problem is that you need to parse the float, from a string to a number first. In that case, it would be: `print("{:.4f}".format(float(lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces())))` Notice the use of float()

Comment: hei , apologies its totally my mistake . `get_accelerometer_g_forces() ` function returns a list of 3 floats like [ -0.5555 , -0.78788 , 0.878888 ]. how can i limit them into 4 digits

Comment: No problem :) Well, in that case you have an array. So you need to specify which position in the array you are interested in formatting; for example `get_accelerometer_g_forces()[0]` for -0.5555, `get_accelerometer_g_forces()[1]` for -0.7878, and so on... If you wish to format ALL of them, then use a loop to do it. I will edit my original answer, to show how to do this.